# onblur event not firing from Html.TextBoxFor helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've followed an example that calls some javascript code from a TextBoxFor helper which looks like this:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(c => Model.Birthdate, new { @class = "datepicker", maxlength = 10, @onblur = "chkBirthday" })%>
```

My javascript, within an asp:Content header looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("blur", "select[name=MainContent_Birthdate]",
    function chkBirthday() {

        document.getElementById("MainContent_ErrorMessage").visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("MainContent_ErrorMessage").innerHTML = 'Testing';

    });
```

I've tried several options to get something back when I tab out of my helper, including just having an alert("Testing") in my function, removing the line $(document), giving elements full names (MainContent prefix) but nothing works.

I'm using Chrome with their dev tools and can see that the element names generated by the helper are correct.  I don't know what's wrong.

Can someone help?

Comment: Unrelated, but something worth bringing up - I've found it's easier to be consistent with how you work with elements.  I notice you're using both vanilla JS and jQuery at once.  The vanilla JS would be easily replaceable with with `$('#MainContent_ErrorMessage').css('visibility', visible); $('#MainContent_ErrorMessage').html('Testing');`  Functionally it's the same, but visually it's superior because it's consistent with your event handler (it's also a character or two shorter to type.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is invalid. you should use `input[name=MainContent_Birthdate]`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the element a TextBox? You are using a selector for a dropdown list (select). Try this:

```
$(document).on("blur", "input[name=MainContent_Birthdate]"
                         ^^^
```

and see if that works.

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/pwWaD/

Comment: Thanks Hanlet, you are correct also.  Unfortunately, I think I can only pick one answer so choosing the first reply seems the fairest way.